# sqlite. Обновить несколько полей в зависимости от условия

Tags: sql, sqlite

У меня есть 2 счетчика. Если приходит положительное число - я увеличиваю счетчик лайков на 1, если отрицательное - увеличиваю счетчик дизлайков на 1 соответственно. Но мой текущий код выдает синтаксическую ошибку.

```
cursor.execute("""
UPDATE posts SET
likes_count = CASE WHEN (?) > 0 THEN
likes_count = likes_count + 1 ELSE likes_count END
dislikes_count = CASE WHEN (?) < 0 THEN
dislikes_count = dislikes_count + 1 ELSE dislikes_count END
WHERE id = ?""", (data,abs(data),))
```

ps. callback data так же является id колонки, в которой нужно обновить счетчик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE post
SET likes_count = likes_count + (? > 0),
    dislikes_count = dislikes_count + (? < 0)
WHERE id = ?
```

и соответственно

```
cursor.execute( sql_text, (result, result, id) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Каждый оператор обновления поля должен преобразовываться в одно значение ( не должно быть 2 `=`). Так же следует добавить `,` после `END`

`THEN likes_count = likes_count + 1 ELSE …
 Должно стать THEN likes_count + 1 ELSE …`